# ElementTransitions doesn't work on jquery loaded pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to use ElementTransitions (https://github.com/dan-silver/ElementTransitions) but it won't work in the page I loaded with JQuery, only working at index page.

It should rotate the div when clicked upon. I wonder if it has something to do with jquery loading and the lib functions. I tried to click the div with JQuery .click() with no success. Even including a page with the below code at the index page with php has no effect.
I am loading the css and js at the head tag as advised by the tutorial page (http://dan-silver.github.io/ElementTransitions/).

```
<div class="et-wrapper et-rotate" et-in="rotateSlideIn" et-out="rotateSlideOut">
    <div class="et-page">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="et-page">
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/elementTransitions/elementTransitions.min.css">
    <script src="libs/elementTransitions/elementTransitions.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  



</body>
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('body').load('controle_acesso.php');

</script>
</html>
```

controle_acesso.php

```
 <div class="et-wrapper et-rotate" et-in="rotateSlideIn" et-out="rotateSlideOut">
    <div class="et-page et-page-current">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="et-page">
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to the tutorial is nice but to get an effective answer, please post your own non-working code so we can see that.

Comment: Link to the tutorial is the last thing at the answer up there. Right after "tutorial page". Will edit to post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's due to your order of loading JS.

All your libraries including the initialization of ElementTransitions are loaded in the HTML-head, while your content, which should be transitioned, is loaded after that via jQuery.

You may try to call `PageTransitions.init();` again additionally after `$('body').load('controle_acesso.php');`.
Or you move the inclusion `<script src="libs/elementTransitions/elementTransitions.min.js"></script>` down after your DOM manipulation.

---

By the way: your *controle_acesso.php* is not valid PHP.
If it really only contains HTML, that use a valid HTML and try loading it via `$('body').load('controle_acesso.html .et-wrapper');`.

Comment: the `PageTransitions.init();` worked perfectly! Moving the script inclusion had no effect, seems like it needs to be at the head tag. My php page has processing and it echoes the html elements after, I just cut it all out. Thanks!!